# When debugging managed System.Windows.Forms code, debugger is skipping lines

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

My understanding is that when a debugger is skipping lines, then the symbol file is incorrect.

The symbols and (I assume) the source came from the microsoft symbol server, but when I step through System.Windows.Forms.Control.cs I am seeing lines skipped.

Any idea on how to fix this?

If it matters, the part of the code I am looking through is the path of a KEYDOWN windows message through the WndProc function.

Comment: That's because the code is optimized.

Comment: Makes sense, but is there any way to solve this issue in light of that? I don't imagine they would include unoptomized dlls with the .Net framework, but is there any kind of workaround?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sburke/2008/01/29/how-to-disable-optimizations-when-debugging-reference-source/